# GitHub Action : How to replace in string in file

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

### Introduction

I'm currently working on a GitHub Action and I want to check if this work for many version of Java.

For this I want to update for each test the *pom.xml* file and change the java inside this.

#### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.pseudo</groupId>
    <artifactId>template</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <name>template</name>
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>JAVAVERSION</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

### Question

Does someone know how we can replace string in file for each test ?

Comment: You want to run your GitHub Action on which os?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I want to test it on macos, ubuntu and windows.

Comment: Why would you like to change the version inside the pom file... Can you explain in detail why you like to do that? And what the purpose of that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this GitHub Action: [MathieuSoysal/replace-string-in-file](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/simple-replace-string-in-file)

Maybe it corresponds to your issue, it works on Macos-latest, Ubunut-latest and Windows-latest.

### Example of usage for your issue

```yaml
name: Test your GitHub Actions

on: [push]

jobs:

  test:
    continue-on-error: true
    strategy:
      matrix:
        java: [8, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19]
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macos-latest]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    name: Test Java version: ${{ matrix.java }} - os: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Replace string in file
        uses: MathieuSoysal/replace-string-in-file@v1.0.0
        with:
          file: pom.xml
          old-string: JAVAVERSION
          new-string: ${{ matrix.java }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Find and Replace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/find-and-replace) GH Action to find and replace the version in your `pom.xml`:

```yaml
name: GitHub Action

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        java: [ '8', '11', '17' ]
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    name: Java ${{ matrix.Java }} sample
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: ${{ matrix.java }}

      - name: Find and Replace
        uses: jacobtomlinson/gha-find-replace@v2
        with:
          find: "JAVAVERSION"
          replace: ${{ matrix.java }}
          regex: false
          include: 'pom.xml'

      # the rest of needed steps
```

This WF will run a `matrix` with different versions of Java and replace the `JAVAVERSION` in the `pom.xml` file with the specific version.

For this example, I also used the [Setup Java](https://github.com/actions/setup-java) GH Action.